# Add operator<< to std::vector

Tags: c++, vector

I want to add `operator<<` to `std::vector<string>`.
This is the operator

```
std::vector<std::string>& operator<<(std::vector<std::string>& op, std::string str) {
    op.push_back(str);
    return op;
}
```

Now I can add elements to vector this way:

```
std::vector<std::string> vec;
vec << "aaa" << "bbb" << "ccc";
```

But the following code isn’t compiled since cant pass temporary object by reference.

```
std::vector<std::string>() << "AAA" << "BBB";
```

How can I change the code to add elements to temporary vectors too?

I have a function which accepts `const std::vector<std::string>&` argument so I want to pass to it a vector in one line.

Comment: What would be the use case for this?

Comment: Why do you need to do this?

Comment: I think the asker is planning to do `takesConstRef(std::vector<std::string>() << "AAA" << "BBB")`.

Comment: @sftrabbit Yes, read the last sentence

Comment: You could do [this](http://ideone.com/fUqifh).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't. The only way it *could* be achieved would be if your operator was a member of the vector. (For some reason member functions can be invoked on temporaries).

As a nonmember function though what you're after is impossible

Also it's not a very good idea to overload operators for STL types such as std::vector. I think what you're trying to accomplish is already present in [**boost assign**](http://www.boost.org/libs/assign/) library. I don't believe you can write it better than they have, so better use boost if you need this.

Comment: Not useless, they provide a perfectly reasonable use case. I might agree with impossible though.

Comment: +1 for boost assign, it looks like really best solution here.

Comment: Why are there several answers that say it's impossible? [seems trivial to me](http://ideone.com/cIL1hK).

Comment: @Mooing Duck: You can try to help, I already tried, even with warning this is not so clear solution (but working answer), got -1 from some idiot who thinks he/she (maybe it?) is very smart :-).

Answer (score 2):

I haven't actually thought about the consequences of this properly, but it seems you could have an overload for rvalues:

```
std::vector<std::string> operator<<(std::vector<std::string>&& op, std::string str) {
  op.push_back(std::move(str));
  return op;
}
```

Yes, it returns by value, but it will be optimized to a move due to §12.8/32:

> When the criteria for elision of a copy operation are met or would be met save for the fact that the source object is a function parameter, and the object to be copied is designated by an lvalue, overload resolution to select the constructor for the copy is first performed as if the object were designated by an rvalue.

Answer (score 1):

Well... technically it is doable but in dirty style. Just for illustration (I'm not so sure it worth real implementation). Checked to work with GCC 4.7.2. I really don't know how this will behave on constant objects.

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

const std::vector<std::string>& operator << (const std::vector<std::string>& op, const std::string &str) 
{
    ((std::vector<std::string>&) op).push_back(str);
    return op;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> a = std::vector<std::string>() << "A" << "B";
    a << "AAA";

    std::cout << "size: " << a.size() << std::endl;
    for (std::vector<std::string>::iterator i = a.begin(); i != a.end(); ++i)
    {
        std::cout << '\t' << *i << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes, but without C++11 requirement.

Comment: Any compiler from the last four years has C++11, and the question doesn't mention a C++03 requirement.

Comment: Well, you are right, but I wrote this code simply to illustrate it is possible after I had seen only 2 answers in the style 'forget about this'. BTW you probably will be surprised how much projects in embedded field are implemented using tools that are older than 5 years. Guess why ;-).

Answer (score 0):

This is a code, that helps you to do something similar to your idea (http://ideone.com/3lrTxW):

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>

typedef std::string String;
typedef std::vector<String> StringVector;

class StringVectorWrapper {
    StringVector vector;
public:    
    operator StringVector&() {
        return vector;        
    }

    StringVectorWrapper& operator << (const String& str) {
        vector.push_back(str);
        return *this;
    }
};
```

And an example of use:

```
#include <iostream>    

void printVector(const StringVector& vector) {
    for(StringVector::const_iterator it = vector.begin(); it != vector.end(); it++)
        std::cout << *it << std::endl;
}

int main(void) {

    StringVectorWrapper w;
    w << "A" << "B";    
    printVector(w);

    printVector(StringVectorWrapper() << "Z" << "W");


    return 0;
}
```

But I would not use such a code in any of my programs.

Comment: @downvoter This is just an example and I think, that somebody can get something from it, so why a minus?

Comment: Because your example is far more complicated than necessary: http://ideone.com/cIL1hK

Comment: @MooingDuck Yes, but your example is in C++11. Mine isn't.

Comment: Any compiler from the last four years has C++11, and the question doesn't mention a C++03 requirement.

Comment: It does not mention any version requirements -- so it's worth, I believe, to show different possibilities.

Comment: Usually when no version is mentioned, it's safe to assume they're referring to the official version.

Comment: But it doesn't exclude giving different examples.

Answer (score -1):

I'm afraid this is not possible. Also it's a bad idea to overload operator for any standard library class. The STL is not meant to be extended.