# How to add an element to a vector by using the << operator?

Tags: c++

As an example, if I want to add elements `"Hello"` and `"World"` to a `std::vector<std::string>` called `v`, I have to use `v.push_back("Hello")` and `v.push_back("World")`.

Instead of this, I want to overload the `<<` operator so I can do this instead:

```
v << "Hello" << "World";
```

In my header file, I have the following function, but it doesn't work:

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, vector<string>& v) {
out << v;
}
```

Comment: 1) you want to push into the vector not into an `ostream`2) your `operator<<` is calling itself recursively. To fix make the operator take a vector and a string (not ostream and vector) and then dont call it recursively but push the string into the vector

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Insert element to vector with `<<` operator or output vector to stream with `<<` operator?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15591603/add-operator-to-stdvector

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add operator<< to std::vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15591603/add-operator-to-stdvector)

Comment: This is quite possible, but it is *a bad idea*, especially if people other than you will be reading the code you write like this. `v.push_back("Hello")` is standard, so it is easily understood what you are doing. `v << "Hello";` will surprise people, and surprise is bad for understanding.

Answer (score 2):

```
v << "foo";
```

Here left hand operand is `vector<string>` and right hand operand is `string`. So this should work:

```
vector<string>& operator<<(vector<string>& v, const string& s) {
    v.push_back(s);
    return v;
}
```

But in my opinion this will be less readable and not a good idea.

Comment: Either pass `s` by `const`-reference or move it when pushing back.

Answer (score 0):

```
vector<string>& operator<<(vector<string> &a,const string &b)
{
    a.push_back(b);
    return a;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for providing code which might help solve the problem, but generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

First a word in forward: A vector is not a stream, and I would rather not recommend doing so. But if you insist: You have to let your vector play the role that normally the stream does, i. e.:

```
std::vector<std::string>& operator<<(std::vector<std::string>& v, std::string s);
```

Well, sure, in the implementation, you'd then call push_back, of course... Use `std::move` when pushing back to profit from move semantics...

You *could* even make it a template:

```
template <typename T, typename V>
std::vector<T>& operator<<(std::vector<T>& c, V v)
{
    c.push_back(T(std::move(v)));
    return c;
}
```

This would allow to add any data type to a vector of arbitrary type, as long as the vector's type is constructible from the value given... Even better, since C++11:

```
c.emplace_back(std::move(v));
```

Comment: `std::string&& s` why would you want an rvalue-reference here?

Comment: with the template you have to be explicit about passing a `std::string` (or add a `const char*` overload).

Answer (score 0):

I agree with [@Caleth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50247647/how-to-add-an-element-to-a-vector-by-using-the-operator/50248199#comment87514636_50247647) on this comment:

> This is quite possible, but it is a bad idea, especially if people
>   other than you will be reading the code you write like this.
>   `v.push_back("Hello")` is standard, so it is easily understood what you
>   are doing. `v << "Hello";` will surprise people, and surprise is bad for
>   understanding.

So just plain adding an overload like other good answer propose isn't something I'd do. However, I don't see anything inherently bad about wanting to "stream" stuff into the vector. It would just be better to make things explicit, so it's perfectly clear we are using a home-brewed utility. So let's add a level of indirection:

```
template<typename T, typename A>
class vec_streamer {
    std::vector<T, A>& target;

    friend vec_streamer const& operator<<(vec_streamer const& self, T const& t) {
        self.target.push_back(t); return self;
    }

    friend vec_streamer const& operator<<(vec_streamer const& self, T && t) {
        self.target.push_back(std::move(t)); return self;
    }

public:
    vec_streamer(std::vector<T, A>& target)  : target(target) {}
};
```

The above is a handy utility that allows us to write this [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17) code (<kbd>[See it Live!](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a0d2ca8dd2d8ecab)</kbd>):

```
std::vector<int> v;
vec_streamer(v) << 1 << 2 << 3 << 4;
```

Note how `vec_streamer(v)` sends a clear message we are doing something with the vector here (and it relies on template argument deduction, hence C++17 is required). The nice thing about this, is that this `operator<<` can be found by ADL (and only ADL, as a matter of fact), so if any templated code uses `operator<<` we can pass in `vec_streamer(v)` and get the expected behavior. A naive overload that accepts a vector as the left parameter won't benefit from that.